# stitching low feature images together

Tags: python, opencv

Is there a way to attach low feature images together from vertical? I have tried OpenCV's ORB, SIFT& SURF, however, if the images have no features or low features, it fails to stitch them together.

I want these images put together:

[image: image 1]
[image: image 2]

Please, let me know if there a way to stitch them together or if blending works?

Comment: Those images are not conducive to feature matching. Feature matching works best with right angle corners as features (such as a checkerboard pattern). Your images have no good features in common.

Answer (score 0):

the feature matching are often based on contours inside images, there is not contours on your both images like corners or particular poylgon. Once openCv can't find contours and so feature, it can't make template matching to check if feature are ok and assembly both images.

If you have some feature despite the image content, try to lower the matching threshold, it will allow algorithm to match feature that are not exactly the same, like in your two differents pictures